# How can I delete the column titles row SSIS inserts when exporting to an Excel file?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

That's my question. I find it frustrating that SSIS is unable to export an Excel file without writing the column names into the first column. However, I'm forced to, since this is the tool we are using right now, but I also need to export an Excel file whose first three rows are reserved for a title and subtitles, before loading a table properly (with column names and all).

So how can I do this? All I've found are references about how to delete all rows (and why you shouldn't do it).

Thanks

Comment: @MartinSmith: no, not at all. SSIS will create a row with column titles anyway. Unless you can provide me with an example showing me otherwise, every time I've tried that I ended up with column titles anyway

Comment: Looks like a known limitation https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/573247/ssis-export-to-excel-creates-column-names-even-first-rows-has-column-names-is-unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the 'OLE DB Destination' instead of the 'Excel Destination' connection. The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider must be registered on the local machine and the ssis setting 'Run64BitRuntime' must be set to false. You can download the Jet engine from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255.

This connection type has a 'HDR' property that can be enabled/disabled. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a37e4fe-fb8b-4697-b2aa-d5d744afbbc9/reading-excel-header-using-oledb?forum=csharplanguage